# Azure DevOps, move all work item assignments to new user

Tags: azure-devops

I have User A & User B. User B will take over all  assigned to work from user A.

Is it possible to migrate all work items, & mentions in pull reques etc from user A to user B?

Answer (score 0):

To migrate all work items from user A to B, you could achieve this by using Boards -> Query.

For migration mentions in Pull Request, currently there is no build-in feature to migrate this.

Run a new query to list all the work items assigned to user A

[image]

Choose all the work items and "Right" click to assign to user B.

[image]

Then "Save Items"

[image]